# schedule for update date in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ssms

I want to make schedule that run after every 24 hours in asp.net (global.asax). 
I just want to check current date and date which are store into my database one by one. if date is less than current date then add 7 days into it.

I am just trying but without close the reader update is not possible. this kind of error shows me every time.

```
private static void Task()
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        DateTime Newdate;
        String ct = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateTime CT = DateTime.ParseExact(ct, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Date from tblInsertDate", con);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(rdr["Date"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(dt, CT);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                Newdate = dt.AddDays(7);
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update tblInsertDate set Date=@Newdate", con);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Newdate", Newdate);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I make the schedule in global.asax with the help of timer.

Comment: What error you get _exactly_? On which line? Your `rdr["Date"]` isn't _already_ a `DateTime`? What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Date is nvarchar(50) and stored in database in dd/MM/yyyy format. I want to convert it into Date datatype using c#. So I wrote "DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(rdr["Date"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);" but error is String is not converted into valid DataTime

Comment: Change your `Date` column type from `nvarchar` to `datetime`. And use your `rdr["Date"]` directly within `DateTime.Compare` method because it will be _already_ `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

You have written update query using same connection object inside reader.read(). That means reader would have a open connected connection while reading the data and at the same time another command is trying to update data using same connection. Either you can fixed this by creating another connection object in same loop or same connection object after reader close. I have made a small change, Try use this:- , placed update query out of reader loop

```
private static void Task()
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        DateTime Newdate;
        String ct = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateTime CT = DateTime.ParseExact(ct, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Date from tblInsertDate", con);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
       List<DateTime> dates=new List<DateTime();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(rdr["Date"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(dt, CT);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                Newdate = dt.AddDays(7);
                dates.Add(Newdate);

            }
        }
        foreach(DateTime dt in dates)
        {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update tblInsertDate set Date=@Newdate", con);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Newdate", dt);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code is not working. All dates are updated according to Last date of List Item means suppose In list Item 3/7/2015, 4/7/2015, 5/7/2015. After 2 minutes schedule is run and all dates are updated(7 days added into it). So result must be 10/7/2015, 11/7/2015, 12/7/2015. But Result is 12/7/2015, 12/7/2015, 12/7/2015.

Comment: Condition is not there in your update query. Means, it will update all records  and last date will be the final one for every rows. So you have to add a where condition.

Comment: how to add where condition? is there any other way to do it without foreach loop?